# Removing space around a cell in HTML Tables

Tags: html, html-email

I am trying build my first HTML email. I want the masthead graphic to be flush against the edge of the cell but there is a small white border that I can seem to get rid of. What can be done about this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "
http//www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Wrapper (pseudo body tag) -->
        <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">

                        <!--Body Table-->
                        <table border="0" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="">
                            <tbody>    
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                        <!--Content Table-->
                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td lign="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="" width="">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                                                        <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3ruYAyZeJR3clo3dmJUbW5Ya1E" vspace="0" hspace="0">
                                                                        
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                    
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <table border="1" bgcolor="white" align="center" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" width="600"> 
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>subhead</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Story</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Picture</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Content Table--> 
                                        
                                        <!--Footer Table-->
                                        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white" align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer1</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white"  align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer2</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Footer Table--> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--End Body Table-->

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the margin from the page by adding `style="border: 0px"` then add cellspacing and cellpadding to the table and all parent tables.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "
http//www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px">
    <!-- Wrapper (pseudo body tag) -->
        <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                        <!--Body Table-->
                        <table border="0" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
                            <tbody>    
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                        <!--Content Table-->
                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td lign="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                                                        <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3ruYAyZeJR3clo3dmJUbW5Ya1E" vspace="0" hspace="0">
                                                                        
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                    
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <table border="1" bgcolor="white" align="center" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" width="600"> 
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>subhead</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Story</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Picture</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Content Table--> 
                                        
                                        <!--Footer Table-->
                                        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white" align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer1</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white"  align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer2</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Footer Table--> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--End Body Table-->

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your table. Removed table borders so the tables dont show the borders around every cell and the table itself. Also all images need to have *style="display:block"* so there is no extra spaces around it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "
http//www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Wrapper (pseudo body tag) -->
        <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">

                        <!--Body Table-->
                        <table border="0" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="">
                            <tbody>    
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                        <!--Content Table-->
                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td lign="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        <table width="" border="0" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="black">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="">

                                                                        <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3ruYAyZeJR3clo3dmJUbW5Ya1E" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="display:block;">
                                                                        
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                    
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <table border="0" bgcolor="white" align="center" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" width="600"> 
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>subhead</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Story</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>Picture</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                                                                        <p>divider</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Content Table--> 
                                        
                                        <!--Footer Table-->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                            <tbody>    
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white" align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer1</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color:white"  align="center" valign="top" width="">
                                                        
                                                        <p>footer2</p>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!--End Footer Table--> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--End Body Table-->

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
to all of your tables (unless you're intentionally adding cellpadding etc) - that gets rid of the extra spacing.

Then you should also set all images to have an inline style of display:block;

I just tested that, and it got rid of the extra spacing :)